# format SQL TimeStamp to TimeStamp with timezone

Tags: php

how can I format timestamp from MariaDB to universal time with timezone time from SQL

```
"2018-08-25 00:00:00"
```

wanted format

```
"2018-07-24T08:43:32+02:00"
```

I already tried this but without any result

```
$value['date'] = "2018-08-25 00:00:00"
gmdate("Y-m-d\Th:i:s\Z", strtotime($value['date']) + date("Z"))
```

Comment: It is actually : Timestamp

Comment: @Digi I don't use MariaDB, can you clarify what your exact expected result is from your sample datetime value?  I think it makes better sense for MariaDB to do this instead of asking php.  I can post this as an answer if you like: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=5d5d56ed68f1cbf62d7bd965688b1d9b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [date_format](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_date_format.asp) function on `DateTime` object.

```
$value['date'] = "2018-08-25 00:00:00";
$datetime = new DateTime($value['date']);
$required_format = date_format($datetime, DATE_ATOM);
echo $required_format;
```

### [Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/XTYHK21363)

Details:

- `DATE_ATOM` - Atom (example: 2013-04-12T15:52:01+00:00)

Comment: @vieroli pls check again there was a bracket typo - i fixed it just now

Answer (score 0):

I have edited Madhur Bhaiya's code :

```
<?php
    $value['date'] = "2018-08-25 00:00:00";
    $timestamped = strtotime($value['date']);
    $datetime = new DateTime(strtotime($timestamped));
    $required_format = date_format($datetime, DATE_ISO8601);

    var_dump($required_format); // returns '2018-09-25T13:37:52+0200'
```

Comment: Always post an explanation with your snippet with the intent to educate.  It is not common to see developers mix `strtotime()` with datetime objects in the same code.